# Emitted signal arguments to QString

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt6

I'm making a software which allows user to connect compatible signals and slots with a graphic interface. So connections are made runtime with QMetaMethod. I want to be able to connect external devices to this "system". Ive made a lot of progress but Im stuck at one thing...

So my idea was to send json packets (signals) via TCP from external device to Qt based application. This Json packet was containing information about device signals and slots. It allows to connect to a slot with compatible parameters and eventually send another packet to invoke.

The problem is the other way around. I have a Qt signal, which when emitted should be parsed with arguments to a QString and send to the external device via TCP. I have a problem with parsing.

It can be done with Functor type connection, since I can implicitly convert types there and do such thing:

```
void someSignal(int a, float b); //signal declaration
void someSlot(QVariant a=QVariant(), QVariant b=QVariant(), QVariant c=QVariant());//slot delcaration
connect(object1, &ObjClass::someSignal, object2, &ObjClass2::someSlot);
```

Above solution is doable, but I cant get the signal at compile time since it will be provided by the user at runtime.

What Ive found out is that with string connection (QMetaMethod, const char*) you can connect signal to a slot with fewer arguments (for example 0 arguments - which will be always compatible). But I need retrive somehow those arguments to convert them to QString...

There is a hint - when using QueuedConnection, Qt actually stores arguments somewhere, because it invokes slot at event handler loop. Question is if I can access those arguments somehow or maybe those are discarded before invoking slot with fewer args?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that you cannot directly connect to the `someSlot` (which "expects" strings) to `someSignal`. If that's the case, you could consider connecting the signal to a lambda that does the conversion and eventually calls the given slot.

Comment: `someSignal` cannot be determined compile time as its user provided. Signals ofc are compile time created, but its the user who decides which one to use.
So as Im aware I cannot use any lambda (Functor based) connection, you can connect only QMetaMethod to another QMetaMethod.
What I exactly need is when a certain selected by user QMetaMethod signal is emited, I should be able to convert its arguments (its ensured that those types are primitive, QString compatible) to a QString.

Comment: What I want to achive is having such a signal:
`void someSignal(int a, float b);`
but accessed runtime with QMetaMethod and when emitted, handled by something to parse its arguments to QString. 
For example when I emit this signal:
`emit someSignal(1, 3.4);`
I should be able to connect some generic slot that will retrieve those parameters and convert them to QString("1,3.4"). I cannot use lambda or functor based connection.